# How can I trigger a process downstream of a Spark write where a _SUCCESS file is not being written?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Imagine the following scenario:

I've subscribed a Lambda to an S3 `PutObject` event via SNS.  The data producer to this S3 bucket will write a `_SUCCESS` file into a partition upon successful write and my lambda will trigger a downstream job when the `_SUCCESS` file is detected and consume that data. All is well.

I've recently onboarded a new data producer where I'm also subscribed to the S3 `PutObject` event - however this producer doesn't write any `_SUCCESS` files when it's done a write.

Are there any recommended patterns or approaches that would allow for efficiently and reliably detecting a completed "full write"? (obviously not perfect since there could be a good number of edge cases - looking for a good enough solution to begin with)

My thoughts thus far would try to detect a spike in `PutObject` events for a partition and keep track of the last event timestamps.  Once detected that activity has stopped for a duration of time (post recent activity), the downstream process would then be triggered to consume the new data.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success at using DynamoDB as a metadata tracker for jobs, which also helps to alert on failed jobs.

But your data producer must be able to place the metadata there. On success of a job, simply update the job item in DynamoDB which will trigger a Lambda function that will allow you to continue processing downstream.

`Producer -> DynamoDB -> Streams -> Lambda`